# Can I insert value in matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

Can I get new value in matrix by some condition in Matlab code/functions? such as

If "1" show in row "1", my target value is "1". If 1 show in row "2", target value is "2" and If 1 in row "3", target value is "3".

example

```
Matrix A=[0 0 1 0 0;
   1 1 0 1 0;
   0 0 0 0 1];
```

and matrix target value is

```
B= [2 2 1 2 3];
```

I don't know function to translate value from A matrix to B matrix. please suggest me some example code.  thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get `B` from `A`, use

```
[B, ~] = find(A);
B = B.';
```

This works because if you call [`find`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) with several outputs, the first output tells the row of each nonzero element. The result is a column vector, so a transpose is needed at the end.

Comment: Thank you so much @Luis Mendo, I can solve this problem.